# How to install right version of libevent on OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, telegram, libevent

I want to run [Telegram CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) on my Macbook with latest version of OSX. It worked sometime before, but doesn't work now:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libevent/lib/libevent-2.0.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/tg/bin/./telegram-cli
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried the following -

```
brew unlink libevent && brew link libevent
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libevent
brew install libevent
```

It doesn't help. Looks like TG GLI looks for libevent 2.0.5, but 2.1.8 is installed by brew.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full answer, but constructive partial answers are allowed - and this won't fit in a comment.... downvotes aren't appreciated as I am trying to help.

A little sleuthing tells me that `libevent` includes a `pkgconfig` file at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.1.8/lib/pkgconfig/libevent.pc
```

I have found with other packages (OpenCV in particular) that if you install `pkgconfig` it helps them find the other packages they need. So I am suggesting you do:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

and set its PATH to include the file for `libevent` I mentioned above, then reinstall your Telegram package... something might click.